# How to hide non available attributes on catalog page ? Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, quantity, color-swatches

I want to hide Non-available attributes (i.e. color or size) on catalog page or products listing page. I have tried to get quantity/stock for particular attribute_id and product_id but I did not get it. So let me know how can I do that.

I am using colorselectorplus module for displaying color swatches on my site. See how my catalog page is looking :- http://prntscr.com/du7k13 All the colors attribute are there, available and non-available both. And See how my detail page is looking for same product :- http://prntscr.com/du7kn9. I want to display same like product page in catalog page.

Please Help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

First I got the hint from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996469/attributes-and-inventory-for-child-products-of-configurable

I see the getAvailablePerColor() function in /app/code/local/ModuleMart/Colorsizegridview/Helper/Data.php file , below is the code of this function :-

```
$colorCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('colorsizegridview/settings/color_attribute');
$totalQtyPerColor = 0;

// Get all products with same color
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
$sameColorProducts = array();
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_prod) {
    if($simple_prod->getData($colorCode) == $colorId) {
        $sameColorProducts[] = $simple_prod;
        $totalQtyPerColor += $simple_prod->getStockItem()->getQty();
    }
}
```

So I used some code from this function, because it is useful to get particular inventory based on attribute for product. See my code :-

```
$colorCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('colorsizegridview/settings/color_attribute');
$totalQtyPerColor = 0;
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
$sameColorProducts = array();
$proAttrQty = array();
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_prod) {
    if(is_object($simple_prod)){
        $stockObj = $simple_prod->getStockItem();
        if(is_object($stockObj) && $simple_prod->getData($colorCode) == $theId){
            $exactQty = $simple_prod->getStockItem()->getQty();
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me. Hope this help to you also !